# SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const' (with Vue, Karma, Webpack, PhantomJS)

Tags: webpack, karma-runner, vue.js, babeljs

I have a more-or-less vanilla Laravel + Vue.js app and I am trying to do some [JS testing with Karma and Jasmine](https://medium.com/@dammyammy/running-tests-on-your-laravel-elixir-projects-with-karma-jasmine-webpack-4c47dd34f44f).  If I try to use `() => {}` style functions or keywords like `const` in my tests, they fail with **Unexpected token** errors, however, I do not have a problem using the `import` keyword and I am able to transpile and work with `.vue` files without issue.

A trivial assertion like

```
expect(true).toBe(true);
```

Seems to work fine (see last line)

```
$ ./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start
22 11 2016 11:09:23.250:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.3.0 server started at http://localhost:9876/
22 11 2016 11:09:23.254:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser PhantomJS with unlimited concurrency
22 11 2016 11:09:23.263:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
22 11 2016 11:09:24.025:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket /#U1dCZ7i3UtsC-M3_AAAA with id 84458811
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.004 secs / 0.002 secs)
```

**Then**, if I add a trivial `const` declaration to my test function

```
const myVar = 1
expect(true).toBe(true);
```

I get an error:

```
$ ./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start
22 11 2016 11:10:00.741:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.3.0 server started at http://localhost:9876/
22 11 2016 11:10:00.745:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser PhantomJS with unlimited concurrency
22 11 2016 11:10:00.752:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
22 11 2016 11:10:01.659:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket /#Gwh8ywcLStrKf-ljAAAA with id 78654911
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
  SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const'
  at tests/unit/Example.spec.js:165
```

**Instead**, if I try to cause a syntax error

```
const  = 1   // syntax error
expect(true).toBe(true);
```

then Babel complains (on the first line, before Karma or PhantomJS boots up)

```
22 11 2016 11:07:00.079:ERROR [preprocessor.babel]: /Users/crcarter/Software/CropPlanning/cps-php/resources/assets/js/tests/unit/Example.spec.js: Unexpected token (8:15)
 at /Users/crcarter/Software/CropPlanning/cps-php/resources/assets/js/tests/unit/Example.spec.js
22 11 2016 11:07:00.090:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.3.0 server started at http://localhost:9876/
22 11 2016 11:07:00.091:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser PhantomJS with unlimited concurrency
22 11 2016 11:07:00.101:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
22 11 2016 11:07:00.986:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket /#9Y6QLVxtJ57qRrgDAAAA with id 56249014
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
  You need to include some adapter that implements __karma__.start method!
```

This seems to imply that the `Example.spec.js` file is being parsed/transpiled by Babel, but that the transpiled version is not being delivered to the browser properly, even though the `Example.vue` file seems to be delivered properly.

**What can I do to be able to get things like `const` and `() => {}` to work in my tests?**  Thank you.

Here are the relevant files:

```
resources/assets/js/components/Example.vue
resources/assets/js/tests/unit/Example.spec.js
karma.conf.js                             
package.json
```

---

```
// Example.vue
<template>
    <div class="container">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component ready.')
        },
        data() {
            return { input: '# Hello!' }
        }
    }
</script>
```

---

```
// Example.spec.js
import Example from '../../components/Example.vue';

describe('Example', function () {
    it('should set correct default data', function () {

        const myVar = 1

        // trivial assertions
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

---

```
// karma.conf.js
var path = require('path')
var basePath = './resources/assets/js/';

module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({

        frameworks: ['jasmine'],
        port: 9876,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true,
        browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
        singleRun: true,
        basePath: basePath,

        webpack: {
            resolve: {
                extensions: ['', '.js', '.vue'],
                fallback: [path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')],
            },
            resolveLoader: {
                fallback: [path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')]
            },
            module: {
                loaders: [
                  { test: /\.vue$/, loader: 'vue' },
                  { test: /\.js$/,  loader: 'babel',
                    include: basePath,
                  }
                ]
            }
        },

        webpackMiddleware: {
            noInfo: true,
            stats: 'errors-only'
        },

        files: [
            { pattern: 'tests/**/*.spec.js', watched: false },
        ],

        exclude: [],

        preprocessors: {
            'app.js': ['webpack', 'babel'],
            'tests/**/*.spec.js': [ 'babel', 'webpack' ]
        },

    })
}
```

---

And `package.json`

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "gulp --production",
    "dev": "gulp watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-11",
    "laravel-elixir-vue-2": "^0.2.0",
    "laravel-elixir-webpack-official": "^1.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.2",
    "vue": "^2.0.1",
    "vue-resource": "^1.0.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-babel-preprocessor": "^6.0.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.8.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: please try  expect(true).to.equal(true);

Comment: In the [karma-babel-preprocessor docs](https://github.com/babel/karma-babel-preprocessor) it says:  "As of Babel 6.0, you need to tell Babel which features to use" I don't use webpack, but I can't see you setting the presets anywhere in the code you've shown.

Comment: Like craig said, babel has different stages of es6 support, try use `es2015`+`stage-3` in your `.babelrc`, this combination transpiles all well in my case.

Comment: Thank you for the comments @craig_h and PanJunjie.  I was eventually able to create a working config.  See my answer for details if you're curious.

Answer (score 4):

The comments by @craig_h and @PanJunjie set me on the track of looking at the configuration for `karma-babel-preprocessor`, which led me to the config for `karma-webpack`.  I'm still not sure what was causing the original problem, but it appears that my webpack config for Karma was incorrect or incomplete, and was failing silently.  I added `babel-loader` and `babel-preset-es2015` packages via

```
yarn add babel-loader babel-preset-es2015
```

And then I redid and cleaned up my `karma.conf.js` as such:

```
module.exports = function(config) {

    config.set({

        singleRun: false, // false => watch for changes and rerun tests
        autoWatch: true, // enable / disable watching files & then run tests

        frameworks: ['jasmine'],
        browsers: ['PhantomJS'],

        // Options: LOG_DISABLE, LOG_ERROR, LOG_WARN, LOG_INFO, LOG_DEBUG
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

        basePath: './resources/assets/js/',

        files: [
            { pattern: 'tests/**/*.spec.js', watched: false },
        ],

        // how to process files before serving them to the browser for testing
        preprocessors: {
            'app.js': ['webpack'],
            'tests/**/*.spec.js': ['webpack'],
        },

        webpack: {
            module: {
                loaders: [
                    { test: /\.vue$/, loader: 'vue' },
                    { test: /\.js$/,
                      loader: 'babel-loader',
                      exclude: /node_modules/,
                      query: { presets: ['es2015'] }
                    }
                ]
            },
            // make sure to use the stand-alone version of Vue
            resolve: {
                alias: {vue: 'vue/dist/vue.js'}
            }
        },

        webpackMiddleware: {
          noInfo: true,
          stats: 'errors-only'
        }
    });
};
```

My `package.json` now looks like this:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "gulp --production",
    "dev": "gulp watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-11",
    "laravel-elixir-vue-2": "^0.2.0",
    "laravel-elixir-webpack-official": "^1.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.2",
    "vue": "^2.0.1",
    "vue-resource": "^1.0.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.8",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-babel-preprocessor": "^6.0.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.8.0"
  }
}
```

With all of that, I can now use all of the ES2015 goodness like `const` and `() => {}`.  Sorry to answer my own question, but I hope this helps someone else that encounters a similar issue.

Comment: You can always answer your own question! This is a little late but I suspect that it's because `const` is ES2015, and PhantomJS doesn't support this yet (https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/14506). Babel probably compiled that away to more compatible JavaScript for you before being executed by PhantomJS.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem (though not identical; your configuration is pretty specific). I was also using Vue, karma, webpack, and phantomjs (as configured in the vue-Webpack template).

However, my problem is that I was defining `const` in a helper file that was getting imported into my app. When I changed `const` to `var` in that file, the tests were able to run.(It didn't matter whether or not `const` was used in other files that were already within the `src` directory).

This problem was fixed when I moved this helper file into my `src` folder or one of its subdirectories. I'm too much of a novice to know why this solved the problem, but I'm guessing that babel wasn't configured to work in the root folder, and was only pointed towards the `src` folder.

Hopefully this is helpful for others as well.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to RyanQuey's comment: he is right. The default Vue + Webpack CLI set-up only includes certain contexts to be handled by the babel-loader. Look into build/webpack.base.conf.js and then to the module rule for JS-files. You can see that only the src, test and node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client paths are included (at the time of this writing).