# Angular2 + Mobx + Ng2-mobx w/angular-cli

Tags: angular, mobx

So, my project is using angular-cli version 1.0.0-beta.20-4.
I have successfully integrated Ng2-mobx into the project, it works great!
All components that should access the state are able to, and the UI template is updated thanks to the `*mobxAutorun` directive.

Now, when I run `ng test`, the tests fail with this error:

```
06 01 2017 15:46:50.740:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket /#RCPcM_Qcuf-M86Z1AAAA with id 25747719
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
  SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const'
  at webpack:///dev/ui/~/ng2-mobx/dist/ng2-mobx.js:11:0 <- src/main/js/test.ts:92028

PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
  SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const'
  at webpack:///dev/ui/~/ng2-mobx/dist/ng2-mobx.js:11:0 <- src/main/js/test.ts:92028
```

Looking at `ng2-mobx.js:11` there is a const definition that is a reference to `@angular/core`.

```
const core_1 = require("@angular/core");
```

This seems like something is missing, not sure what though.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an issue opened on the PhantomJS repository:

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2407

And also another thread on SO which talks about a similar issue on a different stack:

[SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const' (with Vue, Karma, Webpack, PhantomJS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40747123/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-const-with-vue-karma-webpack-phantomjs)

edit:

PhantomJS 2.5.0 Beta is now available and comes with a full ES2015 support. It could solve your problem